# using $set on db.collection.save

Tags: mongodb

I'am trying to add to date fields and some user info fields to a document, when inserting it into mongo (using db.collection.save).

Here is my code:

```
    collection.save(
        {document},
        {
            $set: {
                "document.createdBy": "2",
                "document.updatedBy": "2",
                "document.created": new Date(),
                "document.updated": new Date()
            }
        },
        (err, result) => {
      if (err){
        res.status(500).json({ status: 'something is wrong' })
        //return next(err);
      }else{
        res.status(200).json({ status: 'ok' })
        //return next();
      }
    });
```

Mongo only inserts the document and none if the fields in the $set. Any ideas to what I'am doing wrong?

Comment: what is in {document}, also describe how your document looks?

Comment: document is a json object, that looks like this: {"id":"5b72d1125e5f180b6cfeca0e","date":"01-08-2018","number":"77"}

Comment: Maybe there is no such document with this query `{"id":"5b72d1125e5f180b6cfeca0e","date":"01-08-2018","number":"77"}` hence creating new document. make upsert:false, to avoid creating new doc

Comment: There isen't such a document. I'am using the save function to create a new one (inserting), which works fine for the document object, but not for the fields in the $set. Should I use upsert:true to be able to save the fields from $set?

Comment: there is not argument for `$set` in `save` query in mongodb

Comment: Any ideas how I then add date fields and user information on the document I am creating? Is the only method to use insert instead of save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no argument for the [**`$set`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator in [**`.save()`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/) query in mongodb

So instead try to append the object before the query

```
document.createdBy = "2",
document.updatedBy = "2",
document.created = new Date(),
document.updated = new Date()

collection.save(document, (err, result) => {
  if (err){
    res.status(500).json({ status: 'something is wrong' })
    //return next(err);
  } else {
    res.status(200).json({ status: 'ok' })
    //return next();
  }
})
```

Comment: It seems to work. The only reason I didn't choose that way to start with. Was a concern about compatibility with mongo's currentdate. But it seems to be the same format?

Comment: have you defined any schema or model?

Comment: No, I'am using pure mongo without any model.

Comment: Ok It will work... And the format will be `ISODate()`

Comment: Great, I'll keep it that way. Thanks!